# Plone: Change footer text

Tags: plone-4.x

I'm working on a new site for our Center, using Plone 4.3.3 on Linux. I am also using the Plonetheme Burned. How do I change the footer text to replace the copyright attribution from "Plone Foundation and friends" to my organization?

Answer (score 1):

At least we have two ways to achieve this. One is to edit the registered (template-based) view `plone.footer` through the [**Zope Management Interface (ZMI)**](http://plone.org/documentation/glossary/zmi). This approach seems more straight-forward for new comers.

Click into the `Plone Site`, scroll down to look for `portal_view_customizations (Template customizations)`. You will see all the registered views there, including `plone.footer`.

[image]

Click into `plone.footer` you will see its template file in HTML format. Click on **Customize** button to modify it. Thus you can manage the Plone Footer template.

The above approach is much the same with [Change the Logo](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/change-the-logo.html) in Plone.

Another equivalent way is to create your `plone.footer` viewlet in the filesystem, to override the stock one provided by [plone.app.layout.viewlet module](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/master/plone/app/layout/viewlets/configure.zcml). See http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/viewlets.html for more info. Still, there is an equivalent way to override the template, online search with keywords like `z3c.jbot` for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have three such registered views <br>plone.footer (zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IDefaultBrowserLayer)
plone.footer (plonetheme.colorfulworld.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific)
plone.footer (collective.theme.iwaters.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific)         two of which give errors when I try to customize: "BadRequest: The id "zope.interface.interface-plone.footer" is invalid - it is already in use." If I modify the one that permits it, the changes show in Browse HTML, but do not show up on the web site.

Comment: It seems you need to override the template in your filesystem. First, find out which theme package is used. Let's say, collective.theme.iwaters is used. In your `src` directory, checkout the package source, then you can modify its footer template. See ref at https://plus.google.com/photos/114833061013932542407/albums/5907512529031276993/6041308398946058258